# how to use the script xtext name in generator

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to use the script-name in the generator to create the corresponding java file. For example if my script file would be "WordCount.script" I want to create a "WordCount.java" file. I found out the previous versions exposed this via "resource.className" but it did not work for 2.3.1.

```
override void doGenerate(...

   fsa.generateFile(magic_here + ".java", compile...)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the normalized URI for your Resource using ECoreUtil2. For example;

```
import static extension org.eclipse.xtext.EcoreUtil2.*

....
override void doGenerate(Resource input...

    fsa.generateFile(input.normalizedURI.lastSegment + ".java", compile...)
```

Or, if you want an absolute path, you can leave off the `lastSegment`. You may want to strip the filename off the end (".mydsl" for example) before generation, such as in:

```
    fsa.generateFile(input.normalizedURI.replace(".mydsl", ".java), compile...
```

Whatever suits your use case!

Answer (score 0):

The resource has a property URI that encapsulates the name of the file. You may want to access the #lastSegment of it to compute the name of the Java file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
 fsa.generateFile(
    "src"+"/"+"com"+"/"+"stackoverflow"+"/"+"magic"+"/"+ //package
    "more_magic"+".java", //class name
    compile...)
```

The package will be in the src folder and will be 'com.stackoverflow.magic'
You will only see it as a package once you import the files into a project.

Comment: I think the question was about how to get the information which you assumed to be just constant. Also: Why would anyone want to concatenate _constant_ strings by hand in this way?